# Selenium, how to open a link in new window?

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests

Selenium, how to open a link in new window?What I want to do is automate what we do manually by "right click->open in new window".I am aware how to switch to new window if the link is opened in a new window.What I want to do is open in a new window automatically, using selenium.

Comment: Are you using Selenium RC or WebDriver API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Selenium RC you can use the storeEval command to execute a javascript snippet which opens a new window.

```
selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().open('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

This worked for me in FF 3.6 but not 6beta

Comment: Thank you Kieren Dixon.I will check it out (y)