# Python Selenium Loop click through links

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to loop click the links. When I try loop click the links it keeps clicking the first link only.

From the html code, I need the element named "key" value as well. How to capture it.

html file copy in dropbox. Please click `https://www.dropbox.com/sh/85rx13m8iqwax4b/AACNDq_YyOukLh22JNv76vjua?dl=0`.

html code

### https://pastebin.com/Cyg98W2C

Python code I tried

```
elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 200).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//DIV[@id='propertySummaryList']/DIV[@class='summaryListItem   ']/DIV[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/H2[1]/A[1]")))
     elem.click()
     browser.back()
```

Edit: Added dropbox link. Since the site is sign in only. I have made a copy of the page.

Comment: we cant view the contents on that link?

Comment: I do not understand, content of the link after clicking the link? or actual code of where link is available. If it is the 2nd on then yes, there is no href to get the url. I think javascript is handling the link href part. There is an event onclick / onmousedown event.

Comment: i cant see any code from https://pastebin.com/Cyg98W2C

Comment: My bad, first time using the pastebin. Can you check now.

Comment: yes but it would be better if i had a link to the website

Comment: the site is signin only. Can't be viewed without credentials.

Comment: Your xpath is targeting a single a tag without incrementing.

Comment: Please suggest how to do that.

Comment: I have added dropbox link with the html sources.

Answer (score 0):

You can gather all the elements, then use a relative find to find the link you need. Be careful, this may cause stale elements if you don't open the click in a new window.

```
summaryList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//DIV[@id='propertySummaryList']/DIV[@class='summaryListItem   ']")
for elements in summaryList:
    link = elements.find_elements_by_xpath(".//h2//a")
    link.text // or link.click() but need to open in a new window or will get staleElementReference
```

Comment: I have ran the script as per your example. But got error like ```python AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'```

Comment: That's probably because `find_elements_by_xpath` generates a list. Try using `link = elements.find_element_by_xpath(".//h2//a")` instead.

Comment: I guess I am on the right track. As you said I have received staleElement error. I am figuring out how to open links in new tab or window.

Comment: @PatrickKlein I have added dropbox link with html files. Please take a look.

Comment: You can try this to open links in new window: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19152396/1387701

Comment: I tried but getting error. `action = browser.action
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'action'`

Comment: Even when I try to manually CTRL + CLICK doesn't open the links just a blank window, I believe it is due to javascript links.